# Agregar valores a una matriz en python

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Estoy haciendo un proceso de determinar los errores de unos datos respecto a un modelo.
Y estoy haciendo varias distribuciones de puntos de entrenamiento y validación.
Ya tengo generados los distintos archivos csv de las distribuciones.
Ya programé el `for` para leerlos y calcular los errores en cada archivo, pero necesito ir guardando cada iteración en una matriz.
He intentado con `.append` con `.insert` y no me ha funcionado.
Dejo el código que llevo hasta el momento para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
He podido guardar solo la ultima iteración, pero necesito guardarlas todas.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

metrics=[]
#metrics1=np.array()
i=10
#for i in range(10,95,5):
for j in range(5):
    metrics=np.zeros(j)
    datos=pd.read_csv("EVAL%s_%s.csv"%(i,j+1),sep=',')
    real=pd.DataFrame(datos['ORTO'])
    real=np.matrix(real)
    datos1=np.matrix(datos)
    res=datos1[:,8:10]
    fabdem=res[:,1]
    lidar=res[:,0]
    mi=np.min(res,0)
    ma=np.max(res,0)
    errores=real-res
    errorrel=(errores/real)*100
    errorprom=np.mean(errores,0)
    mae=abs(errorprom)
    mae1=mae[:,0]
    mae2=mae[:,1]
    errorcuadrado=np.square(errores)
    mse=np.mean(errorcuadrado,0)
    rmse=np.power(mse,(1/2))
    metrics[j].append(list(mae1[j]))
    #metrics1.assign(RMSE=rmse)
    #metrics1[j]=mae1([j])
```

Comment: En la primera línea adentro del `for` estás asignando un nuevo objeto a `metrics` que sobre escribe la lista vacía que tenías antes del `for` y además lo haces en cada iteración por lo que solo se conservaran los valores de la última iteración.